# Get timestamps by line with iperf3 in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm currently getting this output from iperf3

```
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   0.00-1.00 sec   113 MBytes   950 Mbits/sec      
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   1.00-2.00 sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0     
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   2.00-3.00 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0
```

I want to create Graphics from this data, and as iperf3 can't update timestamps by line (as far as I know..) I'm looking for a way to increment the output file line by line.

result should be like:

```
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   0.00-1.00 sec   113 MBytes   950 Mbits/sec      
2016-03-03 21:33:51 [  4]   1.00-2.00 sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0     
2016-03-03 21:33:52 [  4]   2.00-3.00 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0
```

so an action (+1) has to be done on each line containing **Mbits/sec** until the end of the file.

I guess that sed and/or date command may be helpful and a loop may be useful but can't see how to build it with time values..

Answer (score 2):

```
awk  '$10=="Mbits/sec"\
     {command="date -d "$2" +%s";command |getline $2;close(command)};1' 1txt \
    | awk -vi=1 '$10=="Mbits/sec"{$2=$2+i};i=i+1'\
    | awk '$10=="Mbits/sec"{command="date -d @"$2" +%T";command|getline $2;close(command)};1'
```

tested it on a file 1txt having values:

```
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   0.00-1.00 sec   113 MBytes   950 Mbits/sec      
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   1.00-2.00 sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec    0     
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   2.00-3.00 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec    0
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [  4]   2.00-3.00 sec   113 MBytes   944 bits/sec    0
```

the output as expected after execution was:

```
2016-03-03 21:33:51 [ 4] 0.00-1.00 sec 113 MBytes 950 Mbits/sec
2016-03-03 21:33:52 [ 4] 1.00-2.00 sec 112 MBytes 941 Mbits/sec 0
2016-03-03 21:33:53 [ 4] 2.00-3.00 sec 113 MBytes 944 Mbits/sec 0
2016-03-03 21:33:50 [ 4] 2.00-3.00 sec 113 MBytes 944 bits/sec 0
```

**P.S: you can ofcourse make it more compact and efficient by combining the awk's in a single command. But this helps in better understanding of whats going on.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using *sed*, but this is not trivial... It is much easier to do it using *perl*:

```
perl -lne 'print $1.($2 + ($.) - 1).$3 if /(.+)(50)(.+)/'  file.txt
```

- `-l` enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
- `-n` assume loop around program
- `-e` one line of program
- `print` print command
- `.` string concatenation
- `$number` variables contain the parts of the string that matched the capture groups `()`
- `$.`  the current record number
- `($2 + ($.) - 1)` means:  *50 + 'current record number' - 1*
- `if /(.+)(50)(.+)/'` statement with regular expression referred to by `print`
- `file.txt` file with your datas